# Declaring struct members that are initialised later (C++)

Tags: c++, opencv, struct, initialization, declaration

I need to have a variable that is declared in a struct to be initialised with a value later. It's basically because its initialisation depends on another member of the structure, which only has a value after some functions have been done.

This sounds a bit weird, so I'll show my code:

```
struct frame
{
    Mat thresholded;
    vector<vector<Point> > contrs;
    vector<Moments> momts;
};

frame obj_detect(frame img)
{
    // Get contours from image
    findContours(img.thresholded, img.contrs, CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
    // Initialise moments vector big enough for all contours' moments
    img.moments(img.contrs.size());
    ...
    return img;
}

int main()
{
     frame frame1;
     frame1 = obj_detect(frame1);
     ...
}
```

Currently this code throws this error:
`error: no match for call to ‘(std::vector<cv::Moments>) (std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point_<int> > >::size_type)’`

How should I initialise the moments vector array so that it has enough space for all the contours?

Comment: Why not just use a `std::string` in place of the size and C string fields?

Comment: It's not actually character arrays, it's some weird openCV vector thing. I just put it as char arrays so that it was more general. If that was the wrong thing to do I'll change it.

Comment: Presumably the parts can be stored as variables.   Once you have all the parts collected, use them to create a working instance of your struct.

Comment: @theoB610: OK - so use `std::vector` then ?

Comment: I think it would be more productive for you to study some basic C++.

Comment: `char *` is really very different from `vector<Moments>`.  If your real code is `vector<Moments> my_array;` then the code in `my_function` should be `my_array.resize(struct1.size);`  .  Please post your real code instead of made-up stuff.

Comment: Does `my_function` return `struct1` or something else?

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing wrong or weird about what you're trying to do. This is an example of an initializer function (or what would be called a constructor for a class).

What isn't entirely clear is whether `struct1` is meant to be the struct you are initializing or if it is an input that you are using to return a new struct (since your function does define its return type as `my_struct` as well). In either case, it is generally recommended to pass your structs by reference rather than by value or as return values.

You could try something like this:

```
void my_function(const my_struct& input_struct, my_struct& output_struct)
{
  ...
  output_struct.size = ...;
  output_struct.my_array = new char[output_struct.size];
  ...
}
```

Of course, if you really are using C++, you should question why you are using a struct to represent what seems to be a string?

Once you've allocated memory this way, it is important that you free the memory as well in order to avoid memory leaks. A single object can be deallocated using `delete`, but an array should be deallocated using `delete []`, for example:

```
delete [] some_struct.my_array;
```

Additionally, it is considered good practice to set pointers to null after deallocating them to avoid referencing stale memory segments. This can be done like this:

```
some_struct.my_array = nullptr;
```

Finally, this all gets a bit tedious to manage, particularly if the lifetime and ownership of the object is more complex. To deal with this, the standard library has `unique_ptr` and `shared_ptr` objects that will automatically deallocate an object when it is no longer being used.

I don't think it makes sense to go into detail about the differences and uses of each since there are innumerable resources here and elsewhere on the topic.

Comment: "it is generally recommended to pass your structs by reference rather than by value or as return values" Actually, it is the other way around, unless the required semantics are to modify an existing object.

Comment: I disagree. Passing a struct by value or using it as a return value can be expensive for large structs unless the compiler is able to avoid a copy. This is precisely what the `const` keyword is for, and the reason I included it in my example.

Comment: I wasn't very clear initially. If you need a copy of the struct in the function, then passing by value gives the compiler more leeway to optimize than passing by `const` reference. If you don't need a copy the `const` reference makes perfect sense. If the intention is for the function to initialize a new struct object and give it back to the caller, returning by value is clearer, less error prone, and the copy can often be elided by the compiler anyway, with the new object being build "in-place" on the caller side.

Comment: Agreed. But for people learning the language, I think learning to pass input structs as const references is probably safest. If they need to modify a local copy, they may easily make a local copy to do so and this is unlikely to be any different in terms of performance than passing by value.  As for outputs, I'm somewhat indifferent and each project has its style. For example: https://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.html#Reference_Arguments

Comment: The google C++ style guide is a bit of a running joke in the C++ community.

Comment: Yeah, I'm sure the people at Google think it is hilarious. Besides, what do they know about software?

Comment: Knowing and being good at software doesn't imply knowing C++. The people who wrote those guidelines are probably accomplished C and/or Java programmers.

Comment: Ok, I have revised my question.

Comment: I still think just passing the struct by reference (or as a pointer if you prefer) and initializing it is simplest. You don't need to return anything...

Answer (score -3):

You have to use malloc()

```
char* struct1.my_array = new char[struct1.size];
```

Edited:
Actually you can use malloc or new. In this case - doesn't matter. If you prefer malloc you have to free memory with free(), otherwise you have to use new/delete. Usually new/delete is good to be used while creating objects, when you are dealing with structs and primitive type stick to malloc.

New/Delete operator are usually invokes constructors/destructors and they are a little bit slower than malloc/free. So why you have to pay (even a little) performance cost for nothing?

Comment: `s/malloc()/new[]/` ?

Comment: where does this happen?

Comment: The question is tagged C++, so better to use C++ techniques rather than legacies from C.

Answer (score -3):

Seems to me this is very simple question

```
    my_struct my_function(my_struct struct1)
    {
        ...
        struct1.my_array = malloc(struct1.size); // Initialise the array
        ...
    }
```

Comment: malloc is legacy from c, is there a c++ way of doing this?

Comment: you have to use new as posted by Kamen below